# pdfpage error with url outside margin

Tags: pdftex, pdfpages

A colleague of mine has to merge multiple PDF papers for conference proceedings. 
We tried to use `pdfpage` with the `includepdf` command that works great.

Unfortunately there is a specific PDF that produce an important error in `pdflatex` that stop working during compilation.

We manage to identify that there is one specific page within the PDF that produces the error (using multiple `includepdf` command with the `page` option) and we observe that this page was containing a url that goes beyond the margin of the document.

Do you think that this might produce the error? How to solve it? any strategy is welcome

EDIT: Sorry, did not post the code used, thought it was not that useful, but here it is, with the log file (the pdf to include is called 30.pdf):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{bar}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{between}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{bg}{gray}{0.4}

\newcommand{\overlay}[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[yshift=-1cm] at (current page.north west)
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \fill[fill=bar] (0,0) rectangle
      (\paperwidth,1cm);
    \draw[black] (0,0) -- (\paperwidth,0);
    \node[anchor=base west,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=5pt,
          font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries] 
          (numb) at (0,0.2) {No. #1};
    \node[anchor=base west, minimum height=1cm,
          font=\sffamily]
          (title) at (4,0.2) {#2};
    \node[anchor=base east, minimum height=1cm,
          font=\sffamily]
          (title) at (\paperwidth,0.2) {..};
   \end{tikzpicture}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\setkeys{pdfpages}{pages=-,}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pagecommand={\overlay{30}{epidemics}}]{30}

\end{document}
```

Log file available here http://perso.uclouvain.be/arnaud.browet/small.log

I tried to modify the command to

```
    \includepdf[pages={1-6,8-},pagecommand={\overlay{30}{epidemics}}]{30}
```

which works, so that's why i'm sure that the problem comes from 1 specific page (the 7th)

I don't get an actual result, just a warning box indicating `pdflatex.exe has stopped working` and there is not output produce (PDF file created but "empty")

Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, at least try to add the error message you get …

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've added information to the topic.

Comment: Warning box? If there is more information on the error in the log file please extract that and include it in the question.

Comment: Without the problematic PDFs, we can't hope to answer this: I'm marking as 'unclear' as a result.